# Conservativity theorem

Tags: reference-request, logic

There is an article in Wikipedia titled "Extension by New Constant and Function Names" - see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_new_constant_and_function_names

I have looked through a dozen of mathematical logic textbooks, but could not find a proof of this theorem. So I am looking for a reference to a textbook, containing such a proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is easy to show using completeness/soundness: Every model of $T$ can be expanded into a model of $T_1$ by identifying the constants with the elements of the model that witness the existential formula. Hence every counterexample to a proposition that doesn't follow from $T$ can also be given in a model of $T_1$.

Comment: This is a model-theoretic proof, thank you, but I am also looking for a proof-theoretic one.

Comment: @VictorM I think there's a reasonably simple proof-theoretic proof: given a (say) natural  deduction of $\psi$ (a sentence in the original language) from $T'$, put that entire deduction after an [existential instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation) following a $T$-proof of "$\exists \overline{x}\varphi(\overline{x})$", and convert the result to a natural deduction from $T$, replacing all $a_i$s with the corresponding instantiated variables. This takes a bit of work to flesh out into a complete proof, but the basic idea should be clear.

Answer (score 2):

Page 289 of Elliott Mendelson (1997). Introduction to Mathematical Logic (4th ed.) Chapman & Hall.

Comment: The page 289 contains only a definition of conservative extension,

Comment: Joseph Shoenfield, Mathematical Logic (1967), pag.41-48 : you can find the definition of conservative extension and Lemma 3, used in the proof (Henkin style) of FOL Completeness Theorem.

Comment: You're right, sorry

Answer (score 2):

- Proposition 2.28 on pp. 102-103 of Elliott Mendelson (2015). Introduction to Mathematical Logic (6th ed.) CRC Press.
- Theorem III.3.5 (Extension by Definition) on p. 51 of Stephen Cook, Phuong Nguyen (2010). Logical Foundations of Proof Complexity. Cambridge University Press.
- Section 4.6 (Extensions by Definitions) on pp. 57-61 of Joseph R. Shoenfield (1967). Mathematical Logic. Addison-Wesley.

Comment: in Mendelson Proposition 2.28 requires unique existence, in fact the whole section is about definitions in case of unique existence, see the introductory paragraph of 2.9.  Similarly in Shoenfield.  So these are not references for exactly what the OP was seeking.